# Can't Enable This Python Interpreter Path To Save My Life

Tags: python, path, interpreter

so I'm a newbie, attempting to mess around and install this function on a mac. --

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Si0vFx_dJ5Y&t=416s.

I built this out in Jupyter Notebook and it totally works there, but I'd like to use it in VSCode, instead, so I can have access to the cool layout, terminal, etc., so I can finish connecting the API. That said, I am having a hell of a time trying to connect it in VSCode.

I kept getting advice (from Chat G-P-T) that I don't have the right Python version aligned with my VSCode. It tells me to drop--

/Users/**my-username**/anaconda3/bin/python into the "enter path to a python interpreter" field but every time I do that I can't get anything to happen, and it's like I didn't do anything at all.

Can anyone help me here? I'm pretty frustrated. Thanks.

I kept entering the path that was suggested, and every time I hit enter, it didn't populate into the list of other Python Interpreter versions that were already available.

Comment: Please don't waste your time asking ChatGPT. It doesn't really know how to program. It will give answers that seem plausible but are often wrong.

Comment: you can `print(sys.executable)` from jupyter to know where the interpreter that's currently running python is present and paste it into VScode.

Comment: @ahmedaek Hey, thanks, so that definitely worked, but it brought up the exact same path as what chatgpt suggested, earlier. I tried to insert that same path into the "enter a path to a Python Interpreter" field in Python and it doesn't pull up the app (gradio) that I was trying to use or anything. In output, it just says -- [Running] /Users/(my username)/anaconda3/bin/python "/Users/(my username)/Desktop/Python Projects/audiojontfr.py" But it doesn't actually start the app even though it has the same code as what I put into Jupyter Notebook, which worked.